# Make a row NA starting from a cell in a column

Tags: r, na

I need to make a row NA starting by a cell in a column. Please see the example below:

How can I achieve this in R. Any help is appreciated.

When I use `data <- [!(data$DES6=="F001"),]` it removes 1st and 3rd row in the example below but I need to keep the 1st and 3rd row as shown in the output below.

Thanks in advance.

```
data:

    YEAR  ID  STATE  CROP  CTY  DES1  DES2  DES3  DES4  DES5  DES6  DES7  DES8
    1998  53   CA     11    25  LOO1  50    N     23    W     F001   25    S
    1998  54   CA     11    26  LOO1  61    N     25    W     NA     NA    NA
    1998  55   CO     11    17  LOO1  62    S     26    E     F001   26    N

output:

    YEAR  ID  STATE  CROP  CTY  DES1  DES2  DES3  DES4  DES5  DES6  DES7  DES8
    1998  53   CA     11    25  LOO1  50    N     23    W     NA     NA    NA
    1998  54   CA     11    26  LOO1  61    N     25    W     NA     NA    NA
    1998  55   CO     11    17  LOO1  62    S     26    E     NA     NA    NA
```

Comment: `data[which(data$DES6=="F001"), c('DES6','DES7','DES8')] <- NA`

Comment: Is it `FOO1` or `F001`?

Comment: F001 means Fzerozeroone

Comment: I mean, your example data contain `FOO1`. I just want you to know that this could be a typo.

Comment: Is there a way to specify all the columns starting from "DES6" to the end rather than typing the column names as c('DES6','DES7','DES8')

Answer (score 1):

This will set the matching row to `NA` from the specified column to the end

```
df1[df1$DES6 %in% "F001", seq(grep("^DES6$", colnames(df1)), ncol(df1))] <- NA
```

Comment: So I would like to modify this to use df1[df1$DES6 %in% "F*", seq(grep("^DES6$", colnames(df1)), ncol(df1))] <- NA, will it replace all columns starting from column DES6 for any cell value starting from F.?

Comment: I just noticed in other columns there are cell which has F002, F003 etc. I want to search any cell starting with F* and replace by NA starting from column DES6

Comment: `mydf[rowSums(sapply(mydf, grepl, pattern = '^F')) > 0, grep('DES6', colnames(mydf)):ncol(mydf)] <- NA`